# Profile permissions to deploy from sandbox to production in sales force using Change sets

Tags: deployment, permissions, change-set, custom-profile

I need to deploy apex classes, triggers,objects, customization and visualforce pages from sandbox to production organization using change sets.

What Profile need to clone to create a custom profile and What are the required  permissions need to give to that custom profile in production to allow inbound Change Sets.

I don't want to give full admin permission to user. I need to give only deployment permission.

Please help on this..

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes open profile --> select system admin --> clone the profile

Now checked the **Deploy Change Sets** and remove all other permissions based on your requirement.

Use this profile for any user.

Comment: I think you also need Author Apex if you are deploying Apex, Manage Reports to deploy reports etc.